# Execute Javascript "timer" onclick not working with .click(

Tags: javascript, html, timer, onclick

I would like to get a script to execute only when a button is clicked. I have added the $("").click , but nothing happens. Here is the script :

```
<script language="javascript">
var max_time = 10;
var cinterval;
cinterval = setInterval('countdown_timer()', 1000);

$("#clickme").click(function countdown_timer(){
  max_time--;
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = max_time;
    if(max_time == 0){
    clearInterval(cinterval);
  }
});
</script>
```

And the Html :

```
<button id="clickme" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Execute</button>
```

Where am I wrong ?
Thanks so much !

Edit :
I am adding the html code where the coutdown is displayed :

```
<h1><span id="countdown">10</span></h1>
```

Comment: *"Where am I wrong ?"* `countdown_timer` is not defined in global scope and hence can't be found by `setInterval`. `countdown_timer` is only local to the function itself. But since you say that the click event handler is not executed, I believe you are trying to bind the handler before the element exists.

Comment: Thanks ! How can I fix this ?

Comment: For `setInterval`, pass a function reference instead. For the event handler binding, have a look at the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ . However, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the interval and the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for your links and ideas !

Answer (score 0):

You want to start the countdown on click, so start the interval in the click event

```js
$(function() {
  var max_time = 10;
  var cinterval;

  function countdown_timer() {
    max_time--;
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = max_time;
    if (max_time <= 0) {
      clearInterval(cinterval);
    }
  }


  $("#clickme").click(function() {
    if (cinterval) return; //if timer is running, do not start up again
    cinterval = setInterval(countdown_timer, 1000);
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickme" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Execute</button>
<h1><span id="countdown">10</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, but unfortunately this doen't seem to work... Am I wrong in the html as welle ?

Comment: My guess is you are attaching the click event before the element is rendered. Changed the code to use document ready. The code runs in the snipplet above.

Comment: @espascarello : your solution seems good ! It's not working in my web page, may be because the button and the countdown are in a bootstrap modal... I'll let you know if I find a solution.